# How to create a multi-dimensional ImmutableArray?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

It appears the MS documentation on [ImmutableArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray?view=net-7.0) only refers to one-dimension array. It seems I may be able to wrap an entire array in `ImmutableArray`, then retrieve the entire array first (at index 0), then get the specific value at say [i, j].

```
ImmutableArray<T[,]> arr = ImmutableArray.Create<TVal[,]>(oneDimArray);
T value = arr[0][i, j];
```

Multidimensional arrays seem like a common need to me, and there must be a better way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"Multidimensional arrays seem like a common need to me"*. They're not. Multidimensional arrays are often used in learning exercises but, outside of that, there are generally better data structures. They do have some legitimate uses, e.g. you might use one to represent a chess board, but more of the learning exercises simulate situations where a 1D array or simple list of items with multiple properties are more appropriate.

Comment: As for your example here, I doubt it's useful. I've never used an `ImmutableArray` but I would assume that it means that you cannot assign new values to its elements. That's not going to stop you getting the value of an element and modifying that object, so there's nothing to stop someone changing the elements of your 2D array inside that `ImmutableArray`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I thought array was value type. It's silly because if array is value type then there is no need to wrap it again in ImmutableArray.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments made by *jmcilhinney* that multidimensional arrays are rarely needed, but perhaps that's just my limited experience after decades as a back-end and enterprise developer. Perhaps there are other areas (game development?) where they are more needed...

That said, you can often use [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) instead multidimensional arrays. This is also possible with `ImmutableArray<T>`, although not necessarily particularly easy to work with.

As an example, here's how to initialise a *n×m* immutable jagged array with a default value:

```
public static ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<T>> Initialize<T>(int n, int m, T initialValue)
{
    var inner = Enumerable.Range(1, m).Select(_ => initialValue).ToImmutableArray();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(_ => inner).ToImmutableArray();
}
```

Here's an example of how to initialise a 2×3 array with the default value `"foo"`:

```
var arr1 = Jagged.Initialize(2, 3, "foo");
```

'Changing' values inside of it is awkward at best:

```
// Change value at (0, 1)
var arr2 = arr1.Select(
    (a, i) => a.Select(
        (s, j) => i == 0 && j == 1 ? "bar" : s).ToImmutableArray()).ToImmutableArray();
```

Depending on what you need it for, however, you can write helper methods to make such projections easier.

Since the jagged array is immutable, the above expression doesn't *change* the original array `arr1`, but rather returns a new jagged array `arr2`.

Data retrieval, on the other hand, is easy:

```
// Retrieve value at (0, 1)
string bar = arr2[0][1];
```

As expected, `bar` has the value `"bar"`.

I often work with immutable data structures in C#, but usually I stick with `IEnumerable<T>`. You may have noticed that the above projection makes heavy use of LINQ anyway, so unless you have massive amounts of data, it's not clear why you need something like `ImmutableArray`, jagged or not...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try it out. Just curious in what cases you would stick to IEnumerable<T>? Is it an interface and may have an implementation type that is not immutable. In what cases being immutable is unnecessary?

Comment: @DavidY The `IEnumerable<T>` interface has no methods that allow mutation, so all you can do with it is filtering, projection, folding, etc.

Comment: Hi @Mark Seemann, I tried the jagged array you suggested for both IEnumerable and ImmutableArray. It worked but it seems to work only for small number of elements. For example if I try to construct a 1000 by 1000 array then it causes stack overflow. I also tried a simple IEnumerable and Immutable array for a large number of elements say 1,000,000, and also got stack over flow. Should I use it only for small number of elements?

Comment: On a second thought it could be the algorithm I used to construct the jagged arrays. I used a recursive function that loops through the elements of an array and construct.